# Importing a module that has a parameter which needs to be passed prior to import

Tags: python, parsing, import, discord.py

I know there are a multitude of other questions related to my problem but I have spent the last 5 hours trying the solutions without success for my situation.

I have two files, Client.py and Server.py, Server.py needs to import Client.py and pass a parameter to it prior to importing Client.py because Client has an unresolved parameter that only Server can provide.

Server.py

```
async def Scan(ctx, GUID):         # GUID would be the argument that the Client.py needs 
    from Client import GUIDParse   # Importing the function with the unresolved variable
    GUIDParse.init(GUID)           # Something I tried that didn't work
    import Client
    ....                           #Do stuff from GUIDParse output..
```

Client.py

```
def GUIDParse(GUID):               # GUID being the unresolved parameter 
      print(GUID)
      #Do stuff with GUID...
```

I would accept any idea, my overall objective is to write/parse to the Client the parameter given to Server before the Server imports Client.py.

Comment: You don't have anything to initialize.  There is no `init` sub-function.  That's simply a function that accepts a parameter.  Just do `GUIDParse(GUID)`.

Comment: Thank you, however the problems remains that when I will be importing Client it won't know about the parameter that is passed to it

Comment: It doesn't NEED to know that until you CALL the function.  It's not a parameter to the module, it's a parameter to the function.  It's exactly the same as if you `import sys` and call `sys.exit`.  The `exit` function takes a parameter, but no one cares until it is called.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your problem is that **you cannot import inside a function**, have you tried?

```
#server.py
import Client #import the client first of all
from Client import GUIDParse #then import GUIDParse from Client
#...
async def Scan(ctx, GUID): #inside your function
  GUIDParse.init(GUID)     #you dont need to import it
  #your stuff              #thats why an exception raise
```

Comment: You can, in fact, `import` things inside a function.